# Need help in identifying the correct regex format

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am learning regex and am working on finding the regex format to satisfy below conditions:

1. check the contents in between "<NoteText>" and "</NoteText>"
2. If there is one or more "<" symbol not followed by "!", return all the identified "<" symbols.

example:

```
<NoteText><![CDATA[dvsdhjkndlv        <<<RED>>>  <72901> </NoteText>
```

this should return the 3 "<" before RED and the 1 "<" before 72901

initially i tried with the below regex pattern of negative lookahead.

```
<(?!!)
```

But it returns the "<" before the "NoteText" phrase as well.

I am not sure how to limit the area of filtering in between "<NoteText>" and "</NoteText>".
trying the below way did not work as well.

```
(?:<NoteText>.*)(<(?!!)).*(?:<\/NoteText>)
```

Comment: Using regex to parse complex languages might be possible but will always be much more difficult and prone to error than using a specialized parsers, which are very common for XML

Comment: @Aaron - Agreed, I am parsing XML data into Apache hive tables using a dedicated xmlserde. But there are few preprocessing that i need to do in order to get the XML data to be in acceptable structure for the xmlserde to act on. Hence this query.

Comment: What exactly works depends on which regex engine you are using. Please review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag guidance](/tags/regex/info).

Comment: If your regex engine supports non-fixed-width lookbehind, then you can use [`(?<=<NoteText>.*)<(?!!)(?=.*<\/NoteText>)`](https://regex101.com/r/vTbpTe/1).

Comment: @horcrux - Can you help me with the pattern for java 8 regex engine? Apologies, I should have mentioned the regex engine in my query but missed.

Comment: Does it have to be regex doing the preprocessing, or would you be able to use java code? I could quickly come up with a basic char-by-char parser which would most likely be easier to maintain than a regex and quite possibly perform better than one. That said if you can run arbitrary java code then it's also easy to solve with regex in two steps (select the NoteText content, extract sequences of < from there)

Answer (score 0):

PCRE, not pretty, but working:

```php
(?:\G(?!\A)|<NoteText>)(?:(?!<\/?NoteText>).)*?\K<(?!!)(?=(?:(?!<\/?NoteText>).)*?<\/NoteText>)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/yMylzy/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \G                       where the last m//g left off
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <NoteText>               '<NoteText>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      NoteText>                'NoteText>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    !                        '!'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        NoteText>                'NoteText>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NoteText>                'NoteText>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Can you help me with the pattern for java 8 regex engine? Apologies, I should have mentioned the regex engine in my query but missed.

Comment: @KalpanaVivek It is the same, only with capturing groups and no `\K`, see https://regex101.com/r/yMylzy/2

Answer (score 0):

This is a working method in Java 8. Remember that this works only if you don't have *nested* `<NoteText>` tags.

```java
String myString = "<NoteText><![CDATA[dvsdhjkndlv        <<<RED>>>  <72901> </NoteText>";
Matcher outerMatcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=<NoteText>).*?(?=</NoteText>)").matcher(myString);
while (outerMatcher.find()) {
    String content = outerMatcher.group();  // this is the content of the current NodeText tag
    Matcher innerMatcher = Pattern.compile("<(?!!)").matcher(content);
    int count = 0;
    while (innerMatcher.find()) count++;
    System.out.println(count);  // this will print 4
}
```

The code above is thought for working also with strings of *multiple* occurrences of `<NoteText>` tags.

If you know you have *only one* `<NoteText>` tag, just replace the `while` with an `if`.